# Date conversion to database date

Tags: php, mysql, filter, kohana, date-conversion

I am using Kohana 3.1

**Model:**

```
    public function filters()
    {
        $filters = parent::filters();

        $filters['birthday'] = array(
            array('date', array('Y-m-d', strtotime(':value')))
        );

        return $filters;
    }
```

**birthday input(form value):**

> 23/05/1989

**database output:**

> 1969-12-31

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which of those two outputs are you attempting to get? You are currently telling it to be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD because of the `'Y-m-d'` you are using.

Comment: the first one is the input, then it gets processed in the filters and saves to the database wrong.

Comment: So you want to output to be dd/mm/yyyy? change the sections that currently says `'Y-m-d'` to `'d/m/Y'`. If that is what you are expecting, let me know and I will throw it into an answer. If it is not what you are expecting, write out specifically what you want saved into the database.

Comment: yeah thats the problem. the mysql format is yyyy-mm-dd. but the inputs format is dd/mm/yyyy. I want to convert dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Did you implement that change I already suggested?

Comment: yeah, it outputs 0000-00-00

Comment: array('date', array('d/m/Y', strtotime(':value')))

Comment: `:value` is not valid data to use in `strtotime(':value')` so it will error out and default to epoch

Comment: @Sean how do you suggest I write it to fit the filter?

Comment: It was converting ':value' to time ticks, not the value itself. But now how can i pass the value to strtotime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function filters()
{
    $filters = parent::filters();

    $filters['birthday'] = array(
        array(function($value) {
            return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));                
        })
    ); 

    return $filters;
}
```

Anonymous Methods is the answer!

Thank you all for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt formatting method as a callback filter

```
public function filters()
{
  return array(
    'birthday' => array(
      array('Format::date',array(':value','Y-m-d')),
    ),
  );
}
```

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/filters

Comment: it gives me: ReflectionException [ 0 ]: Class Format does not exist